# Weblogic 12.2.1.2 security realm authenticating but call to isUserInRole returning false.

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jsf-2.2

I have a Java web application that I am working on that is authenticating by using SSO (SPNEGO) token. The security realm and providers are setup in a Multitenancy WebLogic Server (12.2.1.2) and everything appears to be working fine except when a call to isUserInRole is made. It always returns false. The user is being authenticated, a Subject is being created and populated with all of the correct Principals (Groups) from the AD.
I have tried mapping the Principals to a security role assignment in the weblogic.xml file and use that role assignment in the web.xml to try and map the role to a specific Principal (Group) but it is not working as I thought it would.

The application consists of one servlet in the WAR that should display login information to the screen if the authentication succeeds. The authentication succeeds and the information is displayed and I can see my name from the AD and all of the Principals (Groups) that I belong to.

The configuration for the weblogic.xml and the web.xml are as follows.

weblogic.xml

```
  <security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>SITE_ADMIN</role-name>
    <principal-name>@DEV_ADMIN</principal-name>
    <principal-name>DEV_ADMIN</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>AuthSimpleTestServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>functional.test.SimpleTestServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>AuthSimpleTestServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secured pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>SITE_ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
 <login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Admin Role</description>
    <role-name>SITE_ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
```

When I use the browser to test the authentication I am authenticated and the servlet displays my username, all of my Principals and some other information just like it should if I have been authenticated.

**Requested URL:**
http://dev-server:7011/CHAD/SPNEGO_TEST

**Request information:**

Request method: GET

Request URI: /CHAD/SPNEGO_TEST

Request protocol: HTTP/1.1

Servlet path:

Path info:

Path translated:

Query string:

Content length:

Content type:

Server name: dev-server

Server port: 7011

Remote user: DCConway

Scheme: http

Authorization scheme: CLIENT_CERT

Request scheme: http

Request Principal: DCConway

Attempt to Authenticate using HttpServletRequest.authenticate: true

HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(SITE_ADMIN): false

Weblogic Username-> weblogic.security.SubjectUtils.getUsername(Subject): DCConway

Number of Principals from the Subject: 47

**Principal List: (list edited for post)**

DCConway

DEV_ADMIN

@DEV_ADMIN

**Request headers:**

Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*

Accept-Language: en-US

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0

WOW64

Trident/7.0

rv:11.0) like Gecko

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, peerdist

Host: dev-server:7011

DNT: 1

Connection: Keep-Alive

Cookie: JSESSIONID=YAAx-omzQbMg4jE-bedCM-5Guwngj56xAmXVIqhcbFSJxti7Ae6J!2096529829

Authorization: Negotiate YIILJAYG.....

X-P2P-PeerDist: Version=1.1

X-P2P-PeerDistEx: MinContentInformation=1.0, MaxContentInformation=2.0

**Request Attributes:**

weblogic.servlet.network_channel.port: type=java.lang.Integer str='7011'

In the results of being authenticated I can see that using the servlet request to get the remote user works. I can see that using the Principal to get the username works. Calling authenticate using the servlet request works and I can see all of my Principals. I'm at a loss at the moment trying o figure out why the call to isUserInRole is not returning true. I'm guessing that something in the principal to role mapping isn't correct but I don't see where I messed it up yet.

I imagine that I could just use the principals to make the security work and restrict user's based on those but I would really like to know what and where I messed up the mappings or if it's because there are no roles defined in AD just groups. Any explanations are greatly appreciated.